# How to automate a task in org-mode upon clocking out?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use the Emacs org-mode for clocking in and out of work and I would like to automate some specific tasks every time I clock out. For example, I have a shell script to push repositories to a version control system and I would like to do this automatically when I'm finished working (i.e. when I clock out).  This could be extended to every time you clock in as well (e.x. whenever I clock in I want to open my e-mail client automatically).

Any ideas on how to write Emacs lisp in my .emacs file to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a function that does what you need to have done, and add it to `org-clock-out-hook`.  Perhaps something like this (untested):

```lisp
(defun my-on-org-clock-out ()
  (shell-command "commit-everything.sh"))

(add-hook 'org-clock-out-hook 'my-on-org-clock-out)
```

Likewise, there is a hook called `org-clock-in-hook`.